# Creating Falling Snow using HTML 5 and JS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I visited the [Stack Exchange Winter Bash website](http://winterba.sh/) and I love the falling snow! My question is, how can I recreate a similar effect that looks as nice. I attempted to reverse engineer the code to see if I could figure it out but alas no luck there. The JS is over my head. I did a bit of googling and came across some [examples](http://seb.ly/demos/JSSnow/snow3d.html) but they were not as elegant as the SE site or did not look very good.

Can anyone provide some instructions on how to replicate what the SE Winter Bash site creates or a place where I might learn how to do this?

*Edit:* I would like to replicate the effect as close as possible, IE: falling snow with snowflakes, and being able to move the mouse and cause the snow to move or swirl with the mouse moments.

Comment: Are you just asking for the snow-flake-falling effect or also for the mouseover functionality?

Comment: @Bergi - Preferably both, I edited question to reflect what I am looking for.

Comment: I've managed to weed out the snow effect from the rest of the code. Did you want me to post that or are you looking for a "how-to: to do it yourself? It's basically _a lot_ of math that simulates the falling  snow and other goodies.

Comment: Looks like he's looking to accept bad answers :P

Comment: @j08691 - Go ahead and post how they did it. If you want to add some tips and some do it yourself thoughts, go for it. =>

Comment: @j08691: I've looked through the source myself but didn't find the obfuscated/minified code very enlightening. Would be nice if you could post it with some explanation and un-minified variable names :-)

Comment: @Bergi - I said I weeded out the snow code from the other code, but I never said I managed to make sense of it or un-minify it. That could take days! :)

Comment: @j08691: Post it as a wiki answer, let's see what we can do :-)

Comment: I was totally waiting for someone to ask this very question.

Comment: FYI, I plan to publish the winterba.sh snow thing as open source. I'll update when I have.

Comment: @balpha - Wow! Thank You for all the Christmas Gifts, snow has never been so beautiful...well, I am in Colorado (USA).

Comment: @balpha awesome I look forward to seeing it. Mainly in how you handle the rotation of the flakes, I think I have an idea on you you do it but would love to see the code :P

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Great question, I actually wrote a snow plugin a while ago that I continually update **[see it in action](http://loktar00.github.com/JQuery-Snowfall/)**. [Also a link to the pure js source](https://github.com/loktar00/JQuery-Snowfall/blob/master/src/snowfall.js)

I noticed you tagged the question html5 and canvas, however you can do it without using either, and just standard elements with images or different background colors.

Here's two really simple ones I put together just now for you to mess with. The key in my opinion is using sin to get the nice wavy effect as the flakes fall. The first one uses the canvas element, the 2nd one uses regular dom elements.

Since I'm absolutely addicted to canvas here's a canvas version that performs quite nicely in my opinion.

**[Canvas version](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/UdyN6/)**

**[Full Screen](http://codepen.io/loktar00/full/CHpGo)**

```
(function() {
    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
    window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
})();


var flakes = [],
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    flakeCount = 200,
    mX = -100,
    mY = -100

    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

function snow() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for (var i = 0; i < flakeCount; i++) {
        var flake = flakes[i],
            x = mX,
            y = mY,
            minDist = 150,
            x2 = flake.x,
            y2 = flake.y;

        var dist = Math.sqrt((x2 - x) * (x2 - x) + (y2 - y) * (y2 - y)),
            dx = x2 - x,
            dy = y2 - y;

        if (dist < minDist) {
            var force = minDist / (dist * dist),
                xcomp = (x - x2) / dist,
                ycomp = (y - y2) / dist,
                deltaV = force / 2;

            flake.velX -= deltaV * xcomp;
            flake.velY -= deltaV * ycomp;

        } else {
            flake.velX *= .98;
            if (flake.velY <= flake.speed) {
                flake.velY = flake.speed
            }
            flake.velX += Math.cos(flake.step += .05) * flake.stepSize;
        }

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255," + flake.opacity + ")";
        flake.y += flake.velY;
        flake.x += flake.velX;

        if (flake.y >= canvas.height || flake.y <= 0) {
            reset(flake);
        }


        if (flake.x >= canvas.width || flake.x <= 0) {
            reset(flake);
        }

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(flake.x, flake.y, flake.size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(snow);
};

function reset(flake) {
    flake.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
    flake.y = 0;
    flake.size = (Math.random() * 3) + 2;
    flake.speed = (Math.random() * 1) + 0.5;
    flake.velY = flake.speed;
    flake.velX = 0;
    flake.opacity = (Math.random() * 0.5) + 0.3;
}

function init() {
    for (var i = 0; i < flakeCount; i++) {
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width),
            y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height),
            size = (Math.random() * 3) + 2,
            speed = (Math.random() * 1) + 0.5,
            opacity = (Math.random() * 0.5) + 0.3;

        flakes.push({
            speed: speed,
            velY: speed,
            velX: 0,
            x: x,
            y: y,
            size: size,
            stepSize: (Math.random()) / 30,
            step: 0,
            angle: 180,
            opacity: opacity
        });
    }

    snow();
};

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    mX = e.clientX,
    mY = e.clientY
});

init();​
```

**[Standard element version](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/guexx/)**

```
var flakes = [],
    bodyHeight = getDocHeight(),
    bodyWidth = document.body.offsetWidth;


function snow() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        var flake = flakes[i];

        flake.y += flake.velY;

        if (flake.y > bodyHeight - (flake.size + 6)) {
            flake.y = 0;
        }

        flake.el.style.top = flake.y + 'px';
        flake.el.style.left = ~~flake.x + 'px';

        flake.step += flake.stepSize;
        flake.velX = Math.cos(flake.step);

        flake.x += flake.velX;

        if (flake.x > bodyWidth - 40 || flake.x < 30) {
            flake.y = 0;
        }
    }
    setTimeout(snow, 10);
};


function init() {
    var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        var flake = document.createElement("div"),
            x = Math.floor(Math.random() * bodyWidth),
            y = Math.floor(Math.random() * bodyHeight),
            size = (Math.random() * 5) + 2,
            speed = (Math.random() * 1) + 0.5;

        flake.style.width = size + 'px';
        flake.style.height = size + 'px';
        flake.style.background = "#fff";

        flake.style.left = x + 'px';
        flake.style.top = y;
        flake.classList.add("flake");

        flakes.push({
            el: flake,
            speed: speed,
            velY: speed,
            velX: 0,
            x: x,
            y: y,
            size: 2,
            stepSize: (Math.random() * 5) / 100,
            step: 0
        });
        docFrag.appendChild(flake);
    }

    document.body.appendChild(docFrag);
    snow();
};

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    var x = e.clientX,
        y = e.clientY,
        minDist = 150;

    for (var i = 0; i < flakes.length; i++) {
        var x2 = flakes[i].x,
            y2 = flakes[i].y;

        var dist = Math.sqrt((x2 - x) * (x2 - x) + (y2 - y) * (y2 - y));

        if (dist < minDist) {
            rad = Math.atan2(y2, x2), angle = rad / Math.PI * 180;

            flakes[i].velX = (x2 / dist) * 0.2;
            flakes[i].velY = (y2 / dist) * 0.2;

            flakes[i].x += flakes[i].velX;
            flakes[i].y += flakes[i].velY;
        } else {
            flakes[i].velY *= 0.9;
            flakes[i].velX
            if (flakes[i].velY <= flakes[i].speed) {
                flakes[i].velY = flakes[i].speed;
            }
        }
    }
});

init();

function getDocHeight() {
    return Math.max(
    Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight), Math.max(document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight), Math.max(document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight));
}​
```

Comment: Thanks for the information! However there is no snow falling in the Fiddle! I see the flakes moving at the very top but no snow fall.

Comment: Really? What browser are you using? It works in Chrome although I didnt test with any others.

Comment: Hey its snowing! Now can you make the snow fall and form a snowman?...Ha, ha, ha...Just Kidding =>

Comment: @Lynda Just updated it to include some mouse interaction as well.. however its past my bedtime now so I have to stop... I get too addicted to these types of scripts.

Comment: This is so cool. I'm going to run this on our websites over the holiday. Fun idea. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Thanks and there could be worse things to get addicted to, have fun coding in your dreams! I do it all the time, maddening satisfaction!

Comment: heh.. well I didnt go to bed like I wanted to @Lynda went ahead and added a canvas vs as well which I think works and looks much nicer.

Comment: Loktar! I believe it is snowing Christmas for Lynda tonight! Thank you very much! How delightful. I carry green Christmas envy for how fast you can whip up snow flurries. Wow!  Thank you! *grins and giggles*

Comment: @Loktar: [You could also add a random opacity to the elements](http://jsfiddle.net/guexx/10/) in the DOM version.

Comment: @Lynda updated yet again, now the canvas interaction is *really* close to the interaction on the winter bash page.

Comment: You've got a bug in your 'standard version'. In your check that flake.x > body width, you set flake.y to 0 instead of flake.x. This causes weird scrolling issues. Fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/7WH3a/

Comment: @Loktar can u update the source to the current winter bash 2013?

Comment: @KingsleyChew I wrote the snow code, it is not at all related to the winter bash snow, was just a quick example to show one possible way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a pure HTML 5 and js snowfall.
Check it out on my code pen here: https://codepen.io/onlintool24/pen/GRMOBVo

```js
// Amount of Snowflakes
var snowMax = 35;

// Snowflake Colours
var snowColor = ["#DDD", "#EEE"];

// Snow Entity
var snowEntity = "&#x2022;";

// Falling Velocity
var snowSpeed = 0.75;

// Minimum Flake Size
var snowMinSize = 8;

// Maximum Flake Size
var snowMaxSize = 24;

// Refresh Rate (in milliseconds)
var snowRefresh = 50;

// Additional Styles
var snowStyles = "cursor: default; -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; -o-user-select: none; user-select: none;";

/*
// End of Configuration
// ----------------------------------------
// Do not modify the code below this line
*/

var snow = [],
    pos = [],
    coords = [],
    lefr = [],
    marginBottom,
    marginRight;

function randomise(range) {
    rand = Math.floor(range * Math.random());
    return rand;
}

function initSnow() {
    var snowSize = snowMaxSize - snowMinSize;
    marginBottom = document.body.scrollHeight - 5;
    marginRight = document.body.clientWidth - 15;

    for (i = 0; i <= snowMax; i++) {
        coords[i] = 0;
        lefr[i] = Math.random() * 15;
        pos[i] = 0.03 + Math.random() / 10;
        snow[i] = document.getElementById("flake" + i);
        snow[i].style.fontFamily = "inherit";
        snow[i].size = randomise(snowSize) + snowMinSize;
        snow[i].style.fontSize = snow[i].size + "px";
        snow[i].style.color = snowColor[randomise(snowColor.length)];
        snow[i].style.zIndex = 1000;
        snow[i].sink = snowSpeed * snow[i].size / 5;
        snow[i].posX = randomise(marginRight - snow[i].size);
        snow[i].posY = randomise(2 * marginBottom - marginBottom - 2 * snow[i].size);
        snow[i].style.left = snow[i].posX + "px";
        snow[i].style.top = snow[i].posY + "px";
    }

    moveSnow();
}

function resize() {
    marginBottom = document.body.scrollHeight - 5;
    marginRight = document.body.clientWidth - 15;
}

function moveSnow() {
    for (i = 0; i <= snowMax; i++) {
        coords[i] += pos[i];
        snow[i].posY += snow[i].sink;
        snow[i].style.left = snow[i].posX + lefr[i] * Math.sin(coords[i]) + "px";
        snow[i].style.top = snow[i].posY + "px";

        if (snow[i].posY >= marginBottom - 2 * snow[i].size || parseInt(snow[i].style.left) > (marginRight - 3 * lefr[i])) {
            snow[i].posX = randomise(marginRight - snow[i].size);
            snow[i].posY = 0;
        }
    }

    setTimeout("moveSnow()", snowRefresh);
}

for (i = 0; i <= snowMax; i++) {
    document.write("<span id='flake" + i + "' style='" + snowStyles + "position:absolute;top:-" + snowMaxSize + "'>" + snowEntity + "</span>");
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
window.addEventListener('load', initSnow);
```

```css
body{
  background: skyblue;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
    display:block;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<span id="flake0" style="cursor: default; user-select: none; position: absolute; font-family: inherit; font-size: 19px; color: rgb(221, 221, 221); z-index: 1000; left: 226px; top: 561px;">•</span>
```

Answer (score -6):

The falling snow is simple: Create a canvas, create a bunch of snowflakes, draw them.

You can create a snowflake class like so:

```
function Snowflake() {
    this.x = Math.random()*canvas.width;
    this.y = -16;
    this.speed = Math.random()*3+1;
    this.direction = Math.random()*360;
    this.maxSpeed = 4;
}
```

Or something like that. Then you have a timer that, each step, adjusts each snowflake's direction by a small amount, and then calculates its new X and Y by factoring in the Speed and Direction.

It's hard to explain, but actually quite basic.